# How to optimize the following common loop?

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, vectorization, multicore

I have code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void foo(int n, double* a, double* b, double *c, double*d, double* e, double* f, double* g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        a[i] = b[i] * a[i] + c[i] * (d[i] + e[i] + f[i] + g[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int m = 1001001;
    vector<double> a(m), b(m), c(m), d(m), f(m);

    clock_t start = std::clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        foo(1000000, &a[0], &b[0], &c[0], &d[0], &d[1], &f[0], &f[1000] );

    double duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Finished in " << duration << " seconds [CPU Clock] " << endl;
}
```

Can you give me a workable example to optimize it with better performance? Any compiler is fine, like Intel c++ compiler and visual c++ compiler. Please suggest a CPU with  good performance to do such job.

Comment: The question sounds rather broad, but I will give one specific advice: have you verified that the code is vectorized?

Comment: you can try openmp `#pragma omp parallel for` see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP

Comment: I use visual c++ and it is vectorized. Not sure if I can get better performance than compiler's auto-vectorization.

Comment: Depends on what the autovectorizer is doing, can you show the disassembly?

Comment: One thing that could improve your code is if you didn't create multiple vectors of type double but one vector with a struct containing the double values. The reason is that for one loop iteration, the CPU always needs to fetch five values that are in distinct cachelines. Further, I'd refrain from passing the same array but different offsets (`d[0]` vs `d[1]`) to the function. This makes it easier for the optimizer and reader to figure out what's going on.

Comment: BTW: Two obvious optimizations are to drop the for-loop and to drop the call to `foo()` in `main()`. Your code just sums up and multiplies zeroes, giving zero in the end.

Comment: This code will benefit from SIMD/vectorization, especially starting from AVX2 platform (Haswell CPU and later), because of FMA (fused multiply add) instructions. icc and fresh gcc should automatically add FMA when explicit vectorization is enabled. But (not far from your prev. question with multiplication) you will not win a LOT, because the balance between number of load/store vs. compute (arithmetic , operational or cycle-based intensity) is same or worse than in your original case. So you will also have to deal with cache blocking as suggested by gnasher and/or play with prefetch/nt-store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On apple clang, I tried:

- using `__restict__` on the arguments to convince the compiler that there was no aliasing.

result: no change

- distributing the computation over 8 threads in `foo()`

result: computation time **increased** from ~3 seconds to ~18seconds!

- using `#pragma omp parallel for`

result: compiler ignored me and stayed with the original solution. ~3 seconds.

- setting the command line option `-march=native` to allow the cpu's full awesomeness to shine

result: different assembler output (vectorisation applied), but run time still unchanged at ~3s

initial conclusions:

This problem is bound by memory access and not by the CPU.

Comment: I find I am using DDR3 1600 RAM. If I use a better RAM, does it help?

Answer (score 2):

The code in question is useless. It does lots of calculations with uninitialised variables and then ignores the results. Compilers are getting more and more clever at figuring out that kind of thing and removing all the code for this. So don't be surprised if code like this doesn't take any time at all.

In C, you would declare the pointers as "const double* restrict" except a which would be double* restrict, telling the compiler that all pointers except the first one point to data that isn't going to be modified during the loop; this allows the compiler to vectorise. Not a C++ feature unfortunately afaik.

If this was your real problem, you would just swap the inner and outer loop, and remove loop invariants like this:

```
void foo(int iter, int n, double* a, double* b, double *c, double*d, double* e, double* f, double* g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double xa = a [i];
        double xb = b [i];
        double xr = c[i] * (d[i] + e[i] + f[i] + g[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < iter; ++j)
            xa = xb * xa + xr;

        a [i] = xa;
    }
}
```

You'd probably do four iterations in parallel to avoid the latency.

But in a real life situation, you would observe that in each call, you read about 40MB which is way beyond any cache. So you are limited by RAM speed. The usual solution is to split the work into smaller parts, for example 500 elements at a time, so everything fits into L1 cache, then perform  the operation with the same data 1000 times.

Comment: in reality the compiler does not optimise away the loops. restrict made no difference. the problem is memory bound. rearranging the data so the chunks fit in cache would be a reasonable optimisation.

Comment: Richard, did you check all x86 compilers of all versions to make given statement?  As a side comment, this code will benefit from FMA (AVX2, starting from Haswell CPU), especially after cache-blocking (described in given answer) applied.

Answer (score 1):

You could experiment with prefetching the vectors into cache lines and then operating on them in lumps of 8 (8 doubles will fit into every cache line).

Make sure that while you are operating on x[i] to x[i+7] you are prefetching x[i+8] to x[i+15].

This might not help as you are using additions and multiplications which are so fast that your RAM may not be able to keep up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use multithreading. change foo to get fromIndex, toIndex, instead of n and distribute vectores over threads.

```
void foo(int fromIndex, int toIndex, double* a, double* b, double *c, double*d, double* e, double* f, double* g)
{
    for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; ++i)
        a[i] = b[i] * a[i] + c[i] * (d[i] + e[i] + f[i] + g[i]);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the (unfortunately obfuscated) dependence between the values at different indices. If you inverted the loop counter, for example, you would get different results.

Comment: in addition, I tried it. It just slows down the algorithm.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I cant see any dependency between the values at different indexes in foo function!

Comment: Look at how `foo()` is called, you get different offsets into the same arrays. For example, `d` and `e` in `foo()` both reference `d` in `main()`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt only 'a' changes and there is no dependency between 'a[i]' and 'a[i-x]'